# how to get the extender or implementer child's Type

Tags: flutter, dart, inheritance, extends, implements

I have a class:

```dart
abstract class Foo {
   String getName(T f);
}
```

and:

```dart
class Bar implements Foo {}
```

or

```dart
class Bar extends Foo {}
```

how can `Foo` know `Bar` and implement `T` as `Bar`?

***UPDATE***:
I considered statically passing the type of the child, like:

```dart
@override
String getName<Bar>(Bar p1) {
  return p1.name;
}
```

this way I ran into this error: `The property 'name' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'. Try making the access conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!').` 
so, I edited it to be:

```dart
@override
String getName<Bar>(Bar p1) {
  return p1!.name;
}
```

and now I'm getting this error: `The getter 'name' isn't defined for the type 'Bar & Object'. Try importing the library that defines 'name', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'name'.`

I guess the only solution, for now, is using `dynamic` type, like this:

```dart
abstract class Foo {
   String getName(f);
}
```

and

```dart
class Bar implements Foo {
  @override
  String getName(f) {
    return (f as Bar).name;
  }
}
```

but I'd really like to know the answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
abstract class Foo {
   String getName(T f);
}
```

should not be valid. `T` is not specified anywhere.

You need to specify a place for the generic to be passed:

```dart
abstract class Foo<T> {
   String getName(T f);
}
```

Then pass that generic when you extend/implement the abstract class:

```dart
abstract class Foo<T> {
   String getName(T f);
}

class Bar implements Foo<Bar> {
  final String name = '';
  
  @override
  String getName(Bar p1) {
    return p1.name;
  }
}
```

---

If `getName` will always accept an implementer of `Foo`, you can remove the generic and instead use the `covariant` keyword:

```dart
abstract class Foo {
   String getName(covariant Foo f);
}

class Bar implements Foo {
  final String name = '';
  
  @override
  String getName(Bar p1) {
    return p1.name;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for the answer, the `covariant` keyword worked just fine.. until I tried using it in a `List` like: `String getName(List<covriant Foo> f);`, dart is just not understanding it, and I'm getting `Expected to find ')'. ` error. is there any solution for this?

Comment: @Adnan Put `covariant` outside of `List` and make sure it's spelled correctly. `covariant List<Foo> f`